# Copy all the columns vertically in a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
set ws1 As SheetA
set ws2 As Target  
With ws1
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
Lastrow = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Lastcol
    For l = 4 To lastrow
        ws1.Cells(l, i).Copy ws2.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next l
Next i
```

I am trying to copy all the columns in one sheet to another sheet one below the another. Basically copying Column A of Sheet1 to Column A of Sheet2 and then Column B of Sheet1 below Column A of Sheet2 .

Data starts from row 4th of Sheet A in every column, so I kept the second `For Loop` running from 4. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am stuck for hours now. When I run the code it goes in to infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Lastrow` for every column is the same (referenced to `B` Column) then you can try below:

```
With ws1
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim i As Long, LastRow2 As Long
For i = 0 To LastCol - 1
    With ws2
        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws1.Range("A4:A" & LastRow).Offset(0, i).Copy .Range("A" & LastRow2)
    End With
Next
```

You don't need to copy each cell one by one by doing nested `For Loop`.
You can set the first group of cell to copy (`Range("A4:A" & LastRow)`), then just use `Offset` to copy the next column using just one(1) loop.

If `LastRow` for every column is different, you can try:

```
Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
LastCol = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim i As Long, LastRow2 As Long
For i = 0 To LastCol - 1
    LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With ws2
        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws1.Range("A4:A" & LastRow).Offset(0, i).Copy .Range("A" & LastRow2)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. The lastrow for every column is not B. I tried and saw that many records get deleted due to small size of B. How can I change the last row every time? like I can put the column instead of B and put it in the For loop, but then I need to convert the col number in to col letter. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: @Jain No need to convert number to letter. `Cells Property` accepts numeric values for *ColumnIndex* argument. See my edit.